# rails observe_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observer-pattern

i have used observed_field for arrays of data... but i am having trouble making a simple, one field application of it work. i must be missing a very simple detail. have searched extensively for basic syntax and cannot find anything that applies. when i change the selection, the change is not saved and there is no error msg.

```
<% form_for :team, :url => update_item_leader_group_path do |f| %>

    <%= f.select :item_id, @selection_collection %>  

    <span id="trigger_spinner" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="/images/spinner.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </span>

    <%= observe_field 'group_item_id',  
        :url => { :controller => :group, :action => :update_item },  
        :method => :put,  
        :with => "'trig=' + $('group_item_id').value" %>
        :loading => "$('trigger_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'visible'});",
        :complete => "$('trigger_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'hidden'});" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: We need more information like what you really happen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the field is usually something like id='group_item_id', could this be the issue?

Comment: thank you Swards and hurikhan77. the onchange event is now observed so one step closer! i updated the snippet above for your input. now i am getting a syntax error on...

Comment: :with => "'group_item_id=' + escape(value)"

Comment: changing to... :with => "'item_id=' + escape(value)" also results in... syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
    :with => "'item_id=' + escape(value)" ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat "\n"

Comment: @Jay Use `:with => :group_item_id` - no fancy escaping or similar. Rails will do the magic for you. If you really want to use the escape function, use `escape(this.value)`.

Comment: there was an extra character that i took out so the syntax is fixed... but still not saving the data.

Answer (score 2):

The `onchange` event may not be observed until you leave the focus of the select field. To watch some field changes instantly your only option is to use a form observer.

BTW: The `dom id` of your field is probably not `item_id` due to usage of the form builder. @Swards already pointed that out.

Comment: included response to you in comment to Sward above

Answer (score 0):

corrected syntax above
1. form path
2. observer "url"
3. observer "with"

there was also a routing problem. i had to move update_item from a map.resources member to collection